# Mining with intel HD 4000

Tags: dogecoin

I'm new to this. I'm trying to time with my Intel HD 4000, for Dogecoins, just for fun. My CPU gets a miserable 7 khash. GUIMiner has the Intel 4000 HD on the drop down menu, but once I hit start, it says 'Command line options set a device that doesn't exist.' Help?

Comment: Could you specify operating system, laptop/desktop, and if you are using the latest possible version of GUIMINER. You should be using the latest if you got it from http://guiminer.org/ recently.

Comment: @JacobTorba guiminer.org has a small disclaimer in the bottom right reading "This site is not affiliated with GUIMiner and is not the official page of the software." What's up with that?

Comment: @Murch it's weird but the download link checks out. From the proper repository and all.

Answer (score 0):

`GUIMiner` was created for Bitcoin, which uses the `SHA-256` hashing algorithm. Dogecoin uses `Scrypt` as its hashing algorithm, therefore you should use [`GUIMiner-scrypt`](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=150331.0) instead.

Comment: Scrypt gives me the same error, sadly. Is there another driver I need?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that we had three unanswered topics on that subject and subsequently found the above hoping it might be what solves your issue. Another thread was mentioning some SDK that one might have to install. Unfortunately, I don't know very much about mining. I will ask another guy to have a look though.